# SpringBoot - UnsatisfiedDependencyException Spring Boot not Autowiring Repository interface which extends CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Spring Boot application is throwing an exception while starting the server.
Exception is:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'yhcmain.healthcare.repositories.UserRepository' available: expected
> at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
> annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field userRepository in yhcmain.healthcare.service.user.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'yhcmain.healthcare.repositories.UserRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'yhcmain.healthcare.repositories.UserRepository' in your configuration

Controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceResponse response;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> signUpAttempt(@RequestBody User user) {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User createUser(User user) {
        return this.userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository("userRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
}
```

Main Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class HealthcareApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HealthcareApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added yhcmain.healthcare.repositories package in component scan?

Comment: try `@Qualifier("userRepository")` in service when autowiring userRepository (keep both `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier`....

Comment: @FarazDurrani I tried, it is not working.

Comment: @GarimaGupta You made my day. I was under an impression that spring boot automatically scans all the subdirectories present under the root. Adding @ComponentScan(basePackages = "human.healthcare.repositories") removed the error.

Comment: @GarimaGupta Now the server is running but the server is responding with 404 error everytime as I have added componentScan to Repository package which is now become the base package and Spring is now searching for all the other files unde the Repository package.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide Entity's **`primary key`**(ID in Long or Integer) in ***CrudRepository*** Interface in your repository definition and make sure that `@ComponentScan("RootDirectoryURL")` is working fine.

```
...

@Repository("userRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, PrimaryKey> {}

...
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following annotation to your configuration class (HealthcareApplication):

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("<repository-package>")
```